# Calc distance Between two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a problem with my PostgreSQL Database trigger.

I am trying to calculate the distance between two Geo points with PostGIS tools.
The two points are in separate tables, the KEY between those two tables is the `site_id` column.

The `sites` table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE sites(
  site_id INT,
  site_name text,
  latitude float ( 6 ),
  longitude float ( 6 ),
  geom geometry

);
```

The `dots` table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE dots(
  dot_id INT,
  site_id INT,
  latitude float ( 6 ),
  longitude float ( 6 ),
  rsrp float ( 6 ),
  dist INT,
  project_id INT,
  dist_from_site INT,
  geom geometry,
  dist_from_ref INT;
);
```

The goal is the make a trigger that automatically calculates the distance when new Dots are added.

The trigger I created is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dots_insert_site_dist_trigger
  AFTER UPDATE OF "geom"
  ON "dots"
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE dots_insert_site_dist_update();``
```

The function itself:

```
  RETURNS trigger 
  AS
$$
BEGIN
        UPDATE dots SET dist_from_site =
  (SELECT ROUND(100*ST_Distance(NEW.geom, sites.geom))
  FROM
  dots,
  sites
  WHERE sites.site_id = NEW.site_id);
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
 LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

The Error:

> ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
> CONTEXT:  SQL statement "UPDATE dots SET dist_from_site =
> (SELECT ROUND(100*ST_Distance(NEW.geom, sites.geom))
> FROM
> dots,
> sites
> WHERE sites.site_id = NEW.site_id)"
> PL/pgSQL function dots_insert_site_dist_update() line 3 at SQL statement

Site Table:
[image: 1]

Dots Table:
[image: 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at first look seems you missed  join condition in subquery

```
SELECT ROUND(100*ST_Distance(NEW.geom, sites.geom))
FROM  dots
INNER JOIN sites on dots site_id = sites.site_id
WHERE sites.site_id = NEW.site_id
```

and this should generate a cartesian product (m x n rows  between the tables  ..
and as a suggestion you should avoid  the old join syntax based on comma separated  table's name and where condition and use the explicit join syntax with on clause

and you could try using the query as subqiery for update

```
  UPDATE dots 
  SET dist_from_site = t.my_dist
  FROM (
      SELECT dots.site_id, ROUND(100*ST_Distance(dots.geom, sites.geom)) my_dist
      FROM  dots 
      INNER JOIN sites on dots.site_id = sites.site_id 
      WHERE sites.site_id = dots.site_id
  ) t 
  WHERE dots.site_id = t.site_id
```

Comment: I used this code:
```SELECT ROUND(100*ST_Distance(dots.geom, sites.geom))
FROM  dots
INNER JOIN sites on dots.site_id = sites.site_id
WHERE sites.site_id = dots.site_id;```

I got the first distance but how I insert it to the right collum?

Comment: i need to insert the result to the dist_from_site of each row.

Comment: Maby i need to loop the rows and insert each row?

Comment: just a moment  i  try to understand  your comment ..

Comment: Have error
>column t.my_dist does not exist

Comment: i'm sorry .. missed  alias ...answer  updated  with column alias in subquery

Comment: OMG, this is worked!!!
If I want to execute it every time I upload a file, so I will make it function in my PostgresSQL server and call it every time?

I want to say thank you very much!! You made me very happy

Comment: This function works perfectly on small table ' but if I use it on 50K rows the PGDB gets stuck.
Any suggestions?

Comment: for performance  you need  only  ..  indexes .. you must eval the correct presence of index  where needed

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean...
My project using all the 50K rows to get statistics from it.

Comment: you have index on the involved  tables?   ..  You use a subquery with join  and a update with where  ..  these need  proper index  for work fast .. eventually post a new question with the tables schema and the query code you are using

Comment: New question link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66184444/the-query-for-calculating-distance-stuck-the-postgresdb