# The query for calculating distance stuck the PostgresDB

Tags: mysql, postgresql, postgis

I have a problem with my PostgreSQL Database Function.

I am trying to calculate the distance between two Geo points with PostGIS tools. The two points are in separate tables, the KEY between those two tables is the site_id column.

The sites table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE sites(
  site_id INT,
  site_name text,
  latitude float ( 6 ),
  longitude float ( 6 ),
  geom geometry

);
```

The dots table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE dots(
  dot_id INT,
  site_id INT,
  latitude float ( 6 ),
  longitude float ( 6 ),
  rsrp float ( 6 ),
  dist INT,
  project_id INT,
  dist_from_site INT,
  geom geometry,
  dist_from_ref INT;
);
```

The function that calculates the distance is working on small tables but not on 50K rows.

```
UPDATE dots 
  SET dist_from_site = t.my_dist
  FROM (
      SELECT dots.site_id, ROUND(100*ST_Distance(dots.geom, sites.geom)) my_dist
      FROM  dots 
      INNER JOIN sites on dots.site_id = sites.site_id 
      WHERE sites.site_id = dots.site_id AND dots.dist_from_site is NULL
  ) t 
  WHERE dots.site_id = t.site_id AND dots.dist_from_site is NULL;
```

Any idea how to solve the problem on run time and make the PGDB won't be stuck?

Table pictures:

[image: Dots Table]

[image: Sites Table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to repeat the dots table in the FROM clause:

---

```
UPDATE dots d
SET dist_from_site =  ROUND(100*ST_Distance(d.geom, s.geom))
FROM sites s
WHERE d.site_id = s.site_id
AND d.dist_from_site is NULL
        ;
```

---

I hope that `site_id` is UNIQUE, at least in `sites`, otherwise you would get multiple updates per target row.

Comment: The point is: if site_id is **not unique** in the `dots` table, you'd get a *partially carthesian product* in your query.

Comment: The site_id is UNIQUE I will add it to the table configuration.

Answer (score 2):

for performance you should add  these indexes

```
    create index idx1 on dots (site_id, dist_from_site,  geom);

    create index idx2 on sites (site_id, geom);
```

for the second update  try add  also this index

```
 create index idx3 on dots ( geom, latitude, longitude);
```

Comment: How would I add this and using it on the function?

Comment: ... you  must create the indexes  one time only  ...  you can do this with a normal IDE or db console command  ..  as you create a table  ..or add  the index  creation directly after the create tables

Comment: Do I need to change the function?

Comment: no ... You know what is an index .and how an index must be create .. ?

Comment: I don't know what is an index but I created it with the console of the Postgres DB.

Comment: ok  ..  then now your table have the indexes  and can be used by the db engine during the quereis  ..  if the indexes  are good the queries should  run more fastly  ..

Comment: Ok, I get it, still, the DB has stuck, many I need to add geom to the index?

Comment: yes   .. drop the indexes  and recreate  ..  answer  updated ..  with new indexes ..

Comment: you are using then updated ..  in batch execution or in a trigger ?? ..because the update  i posted  work an all the rows   and must executed once

Comment: I need to update only the null rows, the Db still stuck and won't return an answer.
I updated the code.

Comment: but for both the update or just for the one or the second update??  ..is not clear to me .. why you posted  the second update .. ?  if the first is stuck ..  then have not sense ..  poste this code

Comment: The code I posted is the one I use, I updated it so it runs only on null rows.
I am not using any other code.

Comment: the code is composed  by two update ..  two queries .. you should check one by one ..  othewise you cannot understand where is the problem ..  anyway  ..  for performace there only two element  one are indexes  .. second is you db server ..  so if you have bad performance with indexs  could you server is not adeguated  to your need ...

Comment: I don't know about the performance because I am using my MacBook pro.

Comment: then  ..  there nothings more to do  ..  the unique way for improve performance is based on index ,,  if you have applied the indexes i have suggested .. in can't do nothing more,

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help, time, and patient  
The next answer is the one that worked!